# React useReducer don't update state in React context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, use-reducer

React useReducer don't update state in React context. But in return section state data render correctly. Here is sample:

**context.js**

```js
const globalContext = React.createContext();
const initialState = {
  statuses: null,
};
const globalReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_STATUSES':
      return { ...state, statuses: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export const GlobalState = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(globalReducer, initialState);

  return <globalContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>{children}</globalContext.Provider>;
};

export const useGlobalState = () => {
  const context = React.useContext(globalContext);
  return context;
};
```

**comeChild.js**

```js
const { state, dispatch } = useGlobalState();
const testFn = () => {
  console.log(state); // -> {statuses: null} :here is issue
};
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(state); // -> {statuses: null} :as expected
  dispatch({ type: 'SET_STATUSES', payload: 'test str' });
  console.log(state); // -> {statuses: null} :here is issue
  testFn();
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(state); // -> {statuses: null} :here is issue
  }, 3000);
}, []);

return <div>
  {state.statuses && <div>{state.statuses}</div>}// -> 'test str'
</div>;
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Im fairly new to contexts and the useReducer hook my self, but my guess is the good ol' state "logic" in React. React update states asynchronous and not synchronous which can result in these behaviours.

Your reducer and context obviously works, since it outputs the correct state in your return statement. This is because of your `state.statuses &&`  condition, indicating that you want to return the div WHEN state.statuses "exist" so to say.

So to me it doesn't look like any problem, just that React being React with the state updates.

You could `console.log(action.payload)` in your reducer to see when 'test str' enters the reducer action.

Comment: console.log(action.payload) returns 'test str'. Return statement executing before setTimeout. If i set 20000 duration time - result the same.